# app launcher icon is not showing in home screen of android tv

Tags: android, launcher, television, leanback

When I install my app in my tv, I can run it and do everything but I do not know why app icon not showing on the home screen of the tv. Mainly its not displaying in 1080p Tv's

Here is my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.demo.tv">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.app.demo.tv.ACCESS_VIDEO_DATA"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:banner="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/HomeTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/LandingAndOtherTheme" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post AppTheme?

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Leanback">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    </style>  @NguyễnTrungHiếu

Comment: can you share size app_icon?. 
Note: The banner should be an xhdpi resource with a size of 320 x 180 px

Comment: you can check it here: https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start#banner

Comment: yes, banner size is 320 x 180 px in PNG format and its in xhdpi folder

Comment: only in 1080p Tv's its not displaying

Comment: Any update on this? I'm also facing same issue. App banner is not displayed in 1080p TVs

Comment: Creating a default Android TV project with Android Studio 4.1.3 and running it in the emulator will display the logo but it will be cropped. Moving the icon from the drawable folder to the mipmap-xhdpi folder and then reference it with @mipmap in AndroidManifest.xml will solve the issue. The default logo is also in the wrong format according to the docs, it's 432x243@72dpi when it should be 320x180@320dpi.

Answer (score 7):

Just declare icons inside leanback launcher activity

```
<activity
 ...
 android:banner="@drawable/main_logo"
 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
 android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
 ...
 >
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```